# How do I prevent an image's css-filter-drop-shadow from showing up when a div is on top of it?

Tags: html, css, drop-shadow

I am laying a rectangular div on top of a down-arrow image so that only a triangular piece peeks out (I did this by setting the rectangle's z-index to 100 and the arrow's z-index to -100). When I add a drop-shadow to the down-arrow image, I expect only the triangular piece's drop-shadow to appear, but the rest of the down-arrow's drop-shadow that should be hidden under the rectangular div also appears (see image below).

[image].

```
#arrowDown {
position: relative;
z-index: -100; /* z-index of rectangular div is 100 */
width: 88.5839416px;
height: 82px;
margin: -50px 100px;
bottom: 89.2px;

background: url('../img/arrowDown.png') no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FFFFFF);
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FFFFFF);
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FFFFFF);
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FFFFFF);
}
```

Comment: Could you set up a jsFiddle or CodePen so we can give more effective answers? My first guess is that the rectangle is defaulting to `background-color:transparent` because you haven't specified one, which allows the shadow to show through.

Comment: I think that we need to see your code (html,css and js). Like @Brian Bennett said.

Comment: Is the arrow element a child of the rectangle element? Children cannot have a different z-index value of their parents, if the parent is positioned (not static) and also has a z-index value.

Comment: Thanks @RadGH ! The arrow element was a child of the rectangle element. Glad I learned something new today :)